# Computed property not updating from Vuex store object

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a bunch of class binding statements:

```
:class="{active: isActive('status', status.id)}"
```

Here's the method referred to above:

```
isActive: function (param, value) {
    if (!this.activeFilters.hasOwnProperty(param) && value === 'all' && param !== 'type') {
        return true;
    }
...etc
}
```

...and the computed property the method is looking at:

```
activeFilters() {
    return this.$store.state.activeFilters;
},
```

Which is in the Vuex state.

The problem is, these properties aren't updating when one of the dropdowns with the above class binding is clicked on. If I navigate to another route and then back, the active class has been applied just fine. Can I force the computed property to recompute so the class is applied immediately?

I understand that adding properties won't trigger reactivity, [but according to this](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html), if I replace the object with a fresh one, reactivity should be maintained. Well here's what I'm doing:

```
state.activeFilters = query;
```

...replacing the object. I am stumped.

Comment: `this.$forceUpdate();` Is a bad practice. It's not even documented. I think you are doing something wrong. It's not angular. You should avoid this. Can you provide full example on jsfidde/jsbin/codepen?

Comment: I mean basically all the relevant stuff is above - I'm deriving computed properties from a local object that is copied from the state. When the state changes, the computed properties don't update until I re-render - either by my newly discovered (and as you say undocumented) method, or by routing away and then back.

Comment: @daninthemix I think if possible you should find a way to use computed properties for as much as possible, instead of method calls. Method calls, AFAIK, don't re-run when their dependent data changes like computed props do. For example, in this case, `isActiveStatus` could be a dictionary containing `{key: true}` for each `key` that is active. You could then use `:style="{active: isActiveStatus[status.id]}"`.

Comment: To clarify, I think reactivity is not being triggered because `isActive` is a method. Your careful treatmenrt of `activeFilters` can't get around that.

Comment: If you're using Vuex, why are you calling your state directly? You should be using a getter, or at the very least using the mapState to call your state. This whole thing seems a bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Due to limitations in JavaScript, there are types of changes that Vue cannot detect with arrays and objects. You can read more about it here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

**One simple solution is creating a method out of your computed property:**

Before:

```
<Grid v-for="i in items" :items="items" />

<script>
  export default Vue.extend({
    .
    .
    .
    computed: {
      items() {
        return this.storedItems
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

After:

```
<Grid v-for="i in items" :items="items" />

<script>
  export default Vue.extend({
    .
    .
    .
    methods: {
      items() {
        return this.storedItems
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. After my function I need this to force the component to re-render:

```
this.$forceUpdate();
```